# Is there any constant interval in Nservicebus' automatic retries

Tags: exception, nservicebus

I need the figure out how to manage my retries in Nservicebus.
If there is any exception in my flow, It should retry 10 times every 10 seconds. But when I search in Nservicebus' website (http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/errors/automatic-retries), there are 2 different retry mechanisms which are First Level Retry(FLR) and Second Level Retry (SLR).

FLR is for transient errors. When you got exception, It will try instantly according to your MaxRetries parameter. This parameter should be 1 for me.

SLR is for errors that persist after FLR, where a small delay is needed between retries. There is a config parameter called "TimeIncrease" defines a delay time between tries. However, Nservicebus do these retries increasingly delay time. When you set this parameter to 10 second. It will try 10.seconds, 30.seconds, 60.seconds and so on.

What do you suggest to me to provide my first request to try every 10 seconds with or without these mechanisms?

Comment: Stack Overflow encourages you to answer your own questions if you found an answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I answered my question thank you @janovesk

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer;

The reply of Particular Software's community(John Simon), You need to apply a custom retry policy, have a look at http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/errors/automatic-retries#second-level-retries-custom-retry-policy-simple-policy for an example.